# How to Generate an MD5 hash in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, hash, cryptography, md5, sha

Generate MD5 hash of a string using standard library in Kotlin?

I have tried below mention code

```
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.security.MessageDigest

fun md5(input:String): String {
    val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    return BigInteger(1, md.digest(input.toByteArray())).toString(16).padStart(32, '0')
}
```

Is this the best way or which?

Comment: Note that md5 as a cryptography hash is broken and should not be used anymore. Any static scanner will flag it as a weakness / potential vulnerability.

Comment: "Any static scanner..." - that is pretty strong statement given that that JDK uses MD5 internally. See for example: `java.util.UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Using `java.security.MessageDigest` is the simplest way

```
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.security.MessageDigest

fun md5(input:String): String {
    val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    return BigInteger(1, md.digest(input.toByteArray())).toString(16).padStart(32, '0')
}
```

Answer (score 34):

In general, hash (digest) functions take a byte array as input and produce a byte array as an output. Therefore, to hash
a string, you first need to convert it into a byte array. A common way of doing this is to encode the string as an array of `UTF-8` bytes: `string.toByteArray(UTF_8)`

A common way to **display** a byte array as a string, is to convert the individual bytes to their hexadecimal values and concatenate them. Here is an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html) that does that:

```kotlin
fun ByteArray.toHex() = joinToString(separator = "") { byte -> "%02x".format(byte) }
```

[MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) produces a byte array of length 16. When converted to hex, it is represented by a string of length 32.

The full code looks like this:

```kotlin
import java.security.MessageDigest
import kotlin.text.Charsets.UTF_8

fun ByteArray.toHex() = joinToString(separator = "") { byte -> "%02x".format(byte) }

fun hashString(str: String, algorithm: String): ByteArray =
    MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm).digest(str.toByteArray(UTF_8))


fun main() {

    hashString("Hello, world!", "MD5").toHex()
        .also { check(it == "6cd3556deb0da54bca060b4c39479839") }

    hashString("", "MD5").toHex()
        .also { check(it == "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e") }
}
```

**Note** that MD5 has [well known weaknesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security) that make it inappropriate for many use cases. Alternatives include the [SHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms) family of hashing functions. Here is how to apply `SHA-256` on a string:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    hashString("Hello, world!", "SHA-256").toHex()
        .also { check(it == "315f5bdb76d078c43b8ac0064e4a0164612b1fce77c869345bfc94c75894edd3") }

    hashString("", "SHA-256").toHex()
        .also { check(it == "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855") }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest utilsing version 1.15 of Apache commons codec

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.15</version>
</dependency>
```

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(DigestUtils.md5Hex("Hello world!"))
}
```

Comment: It is too big just for md5

Comment: Why add a whole dependency when the JDK has a built in class?

Comment: @duffymo this implementation is more tested and is simple in usage

Comment: More tested than the JDK?   I doubt that.  Wrong two years ago, wrong now.

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.security.MessageDigest

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(md5Hash("Hello, world!"))
}

fun md5Hash(str: String): String {
    val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    val bigInt = BigInteger(1, md.digest(str.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)))
    return String.format("%032x", bigInt)
}
```